# fire sizechanged event in child control - silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I have a custom Silverlight control (control1) inside which I have another custom control (control2). This control2 is added dynamically, not in xaml.

When I resize control1 it doesn't resize control2 automatically. So, I'm trying to find a workaround but not sure how. If control2 is not added dynamically I can manually resize it in control1.size_changed() event. How do I do it?

Comment: when is control2 added to control1? I mean to say, is it dependent on user or developer side to add control2?

Comment: depending on user's action (like button click) it instantiates control2 and add it to control1 like control1.children.add(control2). Actually control1 has a stackpanel, and that's where the control2 is added.

Answer (score 1):

set a boolean variable to true when the control2 is created.
while resizing the control1, you can check whether control2 is there or not with that variable like this :

```
bool blnControl2Set = true;

//resize event of control1
void resize()
{
  if(blnControl2Set)
  {
     //call event handler of control2 resize
  }
}
```

I guess thats what you wanted.
If any further doubt, please let me know.